# What is "position" when referring to the holders of a bond?

Tags: fixed-income, bloomberg, theory

A bond has a "holders" list, available on Bloomberg. I can see "held amount" of each party in USD, but what is the meaning of "position"? Is it a USD value (if you consider it in 1,000s)? What is its definition?

Here is a screenshot which shows held amount in USD, and position, for some of the holders.

[image]

Comment: What does F1 F1 say?

Comment: Have sent a message to them!

Comment: Generally "amount" refers to  a dollar value and "position" to the number of shares, contracts, bonds, barrels, etc. i.e. physical units that you hold. "Price" intermediates between these two. But Mr. Vulis is right that Bloomberg is the best source for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In general, for bonds, loans, and other debt instruments, "position" on reports *usually*, not always, shows the original face value. For example, the bond issuer promised to pay  10 million, and 25% has already been amortized, then the position still shows 10 million, rather than 7.5 million. But some people prefer to see only the remaining principal, while some prefer to see the number of bonds - dividing the total face value by the face value of one bond. Never assume. Always ask whomever generates the numbers, in this case Bloomberg, for their exact definitions.